# Identify a column on right clicking on the column's header

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, syncfusion, gridgroupingcontrol

I have a Syncfusion's [GridGroupingControl](http://help.syncfusion.com/cr/cref_files/windows%20forms/grid/html/d197fe2e-e035-4f17-3bb8-bcac6f18251d.htm). I would like to do a custom action with the column, say a custom "hide column".

There is a way to identify the column name when **right** clicking (I display a context menu by the way) on the column's **header** or cell?

I have a *ContextMenuStrip_Opening*, but it does not bring any info about the column.
I have also *myGrid_TableControlCellClick* but this one action only on the cell and only on the **left** click...

Answer (score 0):

Well, think it

```
    int selected_colum; // "selected_colum " need be a global var

    private void dtg_contatos_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                dtg_contatos.ClearSelection();
                var hti = dtg_contatos.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
                dtg_contatos.Columns[hti.ColumnIndex].Selected = true;
                selected_colum = hti.ColumnIndex;  // here you set to global var de colum to use at contextmenustrip click


                dtg_contatos.Columns[selected_colum].Visible = false; // this you will place at contextmenustrip to hide the column
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: is `dtg_contatos` a GridGroupingControl (http://goo.gl/7yRzjZ) ? Because the GGC does not have a `ClearSelection` method...

Comment: dtg_contatos is a datagridview

Comment: so how the DataGridView is linked to the question?

Comment: in parts work same way, i just tried give you a idea how solve the problem, sorry if isnt what you want, i did my better ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the TableControlMouseDown event on the GridGroupingControl, check for the right mouse button, and then get the ColumnDescriptor from the mouse event location, and save the column name (and maybe HeaderText to show in the menu):

```
    this.gridGroupingControl1.TableControlMouseDown += gridGroupingControl1_TableControlMouseDown;

    private string rightClickCol;

    void gridGroupingControl1_TableControlMouseDown(object sender, Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Grid.Grouping.GridTableControlMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Inner.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            rightClickCol = string.Empty;

            Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Grid.Grouping.GridColumnDescriptor columnDescriptor = 
                gridGroupingControl1.TableControl.GetHeaderColumnDescriptorAt(e.Inner.Location);

            if (columnDescriptor != null)
                rightClickCol = columnDescriptor.Name;
        }
    }

    private void contextMenuStrip1_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rightClickCol))
        {
            hideColumnToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Hide " + rightClickCol;
            hideColumnToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            hideColumnToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Hide Column";
            hideColumnToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    private void hideColumnToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rightClickCol))
            gridGroupingControl1.TableDescriptor.VisibleColumns.Remove(rightClickCol);
    }
```